# Calculus based question

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

For those who knows this stuff this is probably an easy question, but I don't know in general where I should consult to learn solution of this type of problems. So, beside providing solution/hint if you give a good reference to learn this material, I would be grateful. Here is the bottom line of the problem (Note that I simplified a lot to reach this form).

$$
8b(y)=3+2\int b(y)\gamma(y)dy-y
$$

where $\gamma(.)$ is a density function. Find $b(y)$.

Comment: Is $\gamma(.)$ a lower  incomplete gamma function?

Comment: No. It is just a density function where $\int\gamma(y)dy=1$

Comment: Differentiating both sides w.r.t y will give you a linear differential equation that can be solved with known methods.